# how to generate code to initialize a std::vector with a custom Zero value if it exists as T::Zero?

Tags: c++, c++11, structure, sfinae, type-traits

**BACKGROUND**

I have a container class that has a `std::vector<T>` member that I initialize with the constructor that takes `size_t n_items`.  I would like to initialize that vector with my own Zero() function which `returns 0;` by default, but if static member `T::Zero` exists I want to return that instead.

In my first attempt, I use expression SFINAE, but that failed due to ambiguous overload since both the generic version of Zero and the Zero have the same signature with no arguments.  So now, I'm trying to convert the code into classes with `operator()`.

I think I need to use `std::enable_if` somehow, but I'm not sure how to go about coding this.

**FAILED ATTEMPT**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Zero
{
        T operator() const { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Zero
{
        auto operator() const ->
                decltype( T::Zero )
        {
                return T::Zero;
        }
};

struct Foo
{
        char m_c;
        static Foo Zero;

        Foo() : m_c( 'a' ) { }
        Foo( char c ) : m_c( c ) { }
        bool operator==( Foo const& rhs ) const { return m_c==rhs.m_c; }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, Foo const& rhs )
        {
                os << (char)(rhs.m_c);
                return os;
        }
};

Foo Foo::Zero( 'z' );

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        std::vector<unsigned>  v( 5, Zero<unsigned>() );
        std::vector<Foo>       w( 3, Zero<Foo>()      );

        for( auto& x : v )
                std::cout << x << "\n";
        std::cout << "---------------------------------\n";
        for( auto& x : w )
        {
                assert( x==Foo::Zero );
                std::cout << x << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "ZERO = " << Foo::Zero << "\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template<class T, class = decltype(T::zero)>
    std::true_type has_zero_impl(int);

    template<class T>
    std::false_type has_zero_impl(short);
}

template<class T>
using has_zero = decltype(detail::has_zero_impl<T>(0));

template<class T, class = has_zero<T>>
struct zero
{
    constexpr static T get() { return T(); }
};

template<class T>
struct zero<T, std::true_type>
{
    constexpr static auto get() -> decltype(T::zero)
    {  return T::zero;  }
};
```

Usage example:

```
template<>
struct zero<std::string>
{
    static constexpr const char* get()
    {  return "[Empty]";  }
};

struct foo
{
    int m;
    static constexpr int zero = 42;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << zero<int>::get() << "\n";
    std::cout << zero<std::string>::get() << "\n";
    std::cout << zero<foo>::get() << "\n";
}
```

---

Compact version w/o trait:

```
template<class T>
struct zero
{
private:
    template<class X>
    constexpr static decltype(X::zero) zero_impl(int)
    { return X::zero; }

    template<class X>
    constexpr static X zero_impl(short)
    { return X(); }

public:
    constexpr static auto get()
    -> decltype(zero_impl<T>(0))
    {
        return zero_impl<T>(0);
    }
};

template<>
struct zero<std::string>
{
    constexpr static const char* get()
    {  return "[Empty]";  }
};
```

Comment: That `zero` could also be a static member function instead of a static data member.

Comment: It is also possible to use a custom allocator for `std::vector` whose initialization uses the customizable `zero`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline T zero() {
    return T();
}

template <>
inline std::string zero<std::string>() {
    return "[Empty]";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v(1, zero<std::string>());
    std::cout << v[0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: ok - this answers the first half of my problem - is there a way to automagically generate the specialization if Foo::Zero exists and return that one (using C++11 features)?

Comment: @kfmfe04 you might imagine the other half is duck typing

Answer (score 1):

I have a half good news: I found a very simple way (leveraging SFINAE), however the output is not exactly what I expected :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Meat
template <typename T, typename = decltype(T::Zero)>
auto zero_init_impl(int) -> T { return T::Zero; }

template <typename T>
auto zero_init_impl(...) -> T { return T{}; }

template <typename T>
auto zero_init() -> T { return zero_init_impl<T>(0); }

// Example
struct Special { static Special const Zero; std::string data; };

Special const Special::Zero = { "Empty" };

int main() {
    std::vector<int> const v{3, zero_init<int>()};
    std::vector<Special> const v2{3, zero_init<Special>()};

    std::cout << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << v2[0].data << ", " << v2[1].data << ", " << v2[2].data << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned, [the result <strike>is surprising</strike>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93193148b151cd52) *was explained by dyp, we have to be careful not use `std::initializer<int>` by mistake and then read past the end*:

```
3, 0, 0
Empty, Empty, Empty
```

Curly brace initialization yields a different result than regular brace initialization ([see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3494e8942de6401e)) which gives the expected `0, 0, 0`. So you have to use regular braces.

Comment: `zero_init<int>()` yields an `int`, so you have `std::vector<int> const v{3, 0};` which calls the `std::initializer_list` constructor. Yay! for uniform initialization.

Comment: @dyp: Of course, silly me! And since `v[2]` is unchecked it reads past the end (printing the size indicates 2); thanks for catching this I was supposing it had something to do with this but somehow did not get the idea that the vector was shorter than what I expected.